# Log 3rd party messages from stdout and send through a post request in python

Tags: python, logging, python-requests, stdout

Is it possible to log messages that are generated by 3rd party application in python? My code depends on a 3rd party service which is originally implemented in C++, and has python wrapper. It logs various messages through printf() to the stdout. So, when I run my python code with logging, these 3rd party messages aren't logged.

Moreover, I want to send all my log messages to another server through python requests framework. For the messages I log in the python file, I can immeditately send a post request, but what should I do for those 3rd party messages which get directly written to the stdout?

Comment: We need more details about what code you have now, and what is not working exactly

Comment: I had misunderstood my problem earlier. I apologise for that. I have updated my question. I am not sure if any code snippet is necessary to describe my problem, so haven't included any.

Answer (score 0):

One of the simple way is to get the contents in a string and then send it to your server under a specific request. Make your server listen to that request.

Here's is a code to get the logs in a string:

```
import logging
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO      # Python 2
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

log_stream = StringIO()    
logging.basicConfig(stream=log_stream, level=logging.INFO)
```

Comment: My question wasn't clear earlier, I have updated it now. Please suggest if a solution exists.